# Struggling with a button for pay on the table

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this function here that returns my table and inside a table there's a button now I want to be clicked to update a table but somehow it's updating everything when I click on the Pay button in one of the row in my table. I am not sure where I am going wrong with it. Please help

```
    function lue_custom_view()
{
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;


    $output .= '<table>
    <tr style="color: #fff; background: #08a873; font-weight: bold;">
        <th> &nbsp; Account ID</th>
    
        <th>Deposited Amount</th>
        <th>Deposit Date</th>
        <th>Period</th>
        <th>Counter [Days]</th>
        <th>Amount Growth</th>
        <th colspan="2">Total  Return</th>
    
        
    
    </tr>';
    $approve = "Approved";
    $tbl_name  = $wpdb->prefix . "member_deposit";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("select * from  $tbl_name where conf_deposit = 'Yes' AND approve = 'unapprove'");

    $current_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    foreach ($results as $user_data) {


        $startTimeStamp = strtotime($user_data->deposit_date);
        $endTimeStamp = strtotime($current_date);

        $timeDiff = abs($endTimeStamp - $startTimeStamp);

        $numberDays = $timeDiff / 86400;  // 86400 seconds in one day

        // and you might want to convert to integer
        $numberDays = intval($numberDays);

        $realP = $user_data->period;
        $myPeriod = 0;

        if ($realP == 2) {

            $myPeriod = 60;
        }
        if ($realP == 3) {

            $myPeriod = 90;
        }
        if ($realP == 4) {

            $myPeriod = 120;
        }
        if ($realP == 5) {

            $myPeriod = 150;
        }
        if ($realP == 6) {

            $myPeriod = 180;
        }
        if ($realP == 7) {

            $myPeriod = 210;
        }


        $roi = $myPeriod * 0.02 * $user_data->amount +  $user_data->amount;
        $amount_growth = $myPeriod * 0.02 * $user_data->amount;

        $name = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT user_nicename FROM ' . $table_prefix . 'users WHERE ID = ' . $user_data->ID);

        if ($realP == 2 && $numberDays >= 60) {

            $output .= "<tr style='background-color: red; color: #fff'>
        <td> $user_data->ID</td>
        
        <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
        <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td> $realP</td>
        <td> $numberDays</td>
        <td> R$amount_growth</td>
        <td> R$roi</td>
        <td> <form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Pay' /> </form> </td>
        
    </tr>";

            //Add Withdrawal
            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                $todate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_member_history", array(

                    "ID" => $user_data->ID,
                    "amount" => $user_data->amount,
                    "wit_date" => $todate
                ));

                //Update Member Status
                $status = "Approved";
                $where = array('ID' => $user_data->ID);
                $subs = array('approve' => $status);
                $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . "member_deposit";

                $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);


                if ($success) {
                    header('Location: http://empireinvest.co.za/RegSuccess');
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo 'not';
                }
            }
        } elseif ($realP == 3 && $numberDays >= 90) {
            $output .= "<tr style='background-color: red; color: #fff'>
        <td> $user_data->ID</td>
        
        <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
        <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td> $realP</td>
        <td> $numberDays</td>
        <td> R$amount_growth</td>
        <td> R$roi</td>
        <td> <form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Pay' /> </form> </td>
        
    </tr>";

            //Add Withdrawal
            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                $todate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_member_history", array(

                    "ID" => $user_data->ID,
                    "amount" => $user_data->amount,
                    "wit_date" => $todate
                ));

                //Update Member Status
                $status = "Approved";
                $where = array('ID' => $user_data->ID);
                $subs = array('approve' => $status);
                $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . "member_deposit";

                $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);


                if ($success) {
                    header('Location: http://empireinvest.co.za/RegSuccess');
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo 'not';
                }
            }
        } elseif ($realP == 4 && $numberDays >= 120) {
            $output .= "<tr style='background-color: red; color: #fff'>
        <td> $user_data->ID</td>
        
        <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
        <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td> $realP</td>
        <td> $numberDays</td>
        <td> R$amount_growth</td>
        <td> R$roi</td>
        <td> <form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Pay' /> </form> </td>
        
    </tr>";

            //Add Withdrawal
            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                $todate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_member_history", array(

                    "ID" => $user_data->ID,
                    "amount" => $user_data->amount,
                    "wit_date" => $todate
                ));

                //Update Member Status
                $status = "Approved";
                $where = array('ID' => $user_data->ID);
                $subs = array('approve' => $status);
                $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . "member_deposit";

                $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);


                if ($success) {
                    header('Location: http://empireinvest.co.za/RegSuccess');
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo 'not';
                }
            }
        } elseif ($realP == 5 && $numberDays >= 150) {
            $output .= "<tr style='background-color: red; color: #fff'>
        <td> $user_data->ID</td>
        
        <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
        <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td> $realP</td>
        <td> $numberDays</td>
        <td> R$amount_growth</td>
        <td> R$roi</td>
        <td> <form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Pay' /> </form> </td>
        
    </tr>";

            //Add Withdrawal
            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                $todate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_member_history", array(

                    "ID" => $user_data->ID,
                    "amount" => $user_data->amount,
                    "wit_date" => $todate
                ));

                //Update Member Status
                $status = "Approved";
                $where = array('ID' => $user_data->ID);
                $subs = array('approve' => $status);
                $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . "member_deposit";

                $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);


                if ($success) {
                    header('Location: http://empireinvest.co.za/RegSuccess');
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo 'not';
                }
            }
        } elseif ($realP == 6 && $numberDays >= 180) {
            $output .= "<tr style='background-color: red; color: #fff'>
        <td> $user_data->ID</td>
        
        <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
        <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td> $realP</td>
        <td> $numberDays</td>
        <td> R$amount_growth</td>
        <td> R$roi</td>
        <td> <form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Pay' /> </form> </td>
        
    </tr>";

            //Add Withdrawal
            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                $todate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_member_history", array(

                    "ID" => $user_data->ID,
                    "amount" => $user_data->amount,
                    "wit_date" => $todate
                ));

                //Update Member Status
                $status = "Approved";
                $where = array('ID' => $user_data->ID);
                $subs = array('approve' => $status);
                $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . "member_deposit";

                $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);


                if ($success) {
                    header('Location: http://empireinvest.co.za/RegSuccess');
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo 'not';
                }
            }
        } elseif ($realP == 7 && $numberDays >= 210) {
            $output .= "<tr style='background-color: red; color: #fff'>
        <td> $user_data->ID</td>
        
        <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
        <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td> $realP</td>
        <td> $numberDays</td>
        <td> R$amount_growth</td>
        <td> R$roi</td>
        <td> <form method='post'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Pay' /> </form> </td>
        
    </tr>";

            //Add Withdrawal
            if ($_POST['submit']) {
                $todate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

                $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_member_history", array(

                    "ID" => $user_data->ID,
                    "amount" => $user_data->amount,
                    "wit_date" => $todate
                ));

                //Update Member Status
                $status = "Approved";
                $where = array('ID' => $user_data->ID);
                $subs = array('approve' => $status);
                $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix . "member_deposit";

                $wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $where);


                if ($success) {
                    echo "<script> alert('Member order has been approved'); </script>";

                    header("Refresh:0");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    echo 'not';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $output .= "<tr>
    <td> $user_data->ID</td>
        <td> R$user_data->amount</td>
        <td> $user_data->deposit_date</td>
        <td> $realP</td>
        <td> $numberDays</td>
        <td> R$amount_growth</td>
        <td> R$roi</td>
        
    </tr>";
        }
    }
    $output .= '</table>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('views', 'lue_custom_view');

//example usae with php
echo do_shortcode($content,'[lue_custom_view]');
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is the core problem related to HTML, or forms, or is this a pure PHP problem? Also, please remove all the code that is not relevant to the problem itself

Answer (score 0):

1. Having a form without a single input, is kinda pointless. Consider, just using a button and attaching an event handler to it
2. The default behavior of a submitted form is to reload the current page if no `action` attribute is provided with the `method` provided in the respective attribute

With these remarks applied, your code might look like this:

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('row-submit')

for(let btn of buttons) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', rowSubmit); 
}

function rowSubmit(evt) {
  let row = evt.target.dataset.row
  let tr = evt.target.closest('tr')
  console.log(row, tr)
  evt.target.nextSibling.textContent = 'Updated!'
  setTimeout(() => evt.target.nextSibling.textContent = '', 500)
  // do something
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td><button data-row="1" class="row-submit">Submit</button><div></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
    <td><button data-row="2" class="row-submit">Submit</button><div></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```